# Compare elements of list and dictionary and store as list of lists

Tags: python-2.7

This code below

```
dots = [[1,2,73,4],[5,36,7,18]]
pos = {1:(0,6), 2:(4,3),3:(7,5),4:(9,0), 5:(0,28), 6:(4,3),7:(7,5),8:(9,0)}

dot_pos = []
for k in dots:
    for item in k:
        if item in pos:
        dot_pos.append(pos[item])
```

Gave:

```
[(0, 6), (4, 3), (9, 0), (0, 28), (7, 5)]
```

How then can I resolve this to get output like this:

```
[[(0, 6), (4, 3), (9, 0)],[(0, 28), (7, 5)]]
```

Thanks

Comment: Actually the code you provided gives `[(0, 6), (4, 3), (9, 0), (0, 28), (7, 5)]` as an output. Do you want it to be `[(0, 6), (4, 3), (9, 0)],[ (0, 28), (7, 5)]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your desired OP, temporarily make a list and append the item in the list in your if block and then append the content after the inner for loop is executed:

```
dots = [[1,2,73,4],[5,36,7,18]]
pos = {1:(0,6), 2:(4,3),3:(7,5),4:(9,0), 5:(0,28), 6:(4,3),7:(7,5),8:(9,0)}

dot_pos = list()
for k in dots:
    list_temp = list()
    for item in k:
        if item in pos:
            list_temp.append(pos[item])
    dot_pos.append(list_temp)

print dot_pos
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple encapsulation work will be enough. After the loop executes, while you return,may be you return this:

```
return dot_pos
```

For the output you require,

```
return [dot_pos]
```

Answer (score 0):

The code you provided gives `[(0, 6), (4, 3), (9, 0), (0, 28), (7, 5)]` as an output.
Assuming you want to have what you explained the code can look something like this:

```
dots = [[1,2,73,4],[5,36,7,18]]
pos = {1:(0,6), 2:(4,3),3:(7,5),4:(9,0), 5:(0,28), 6:(4,3),7:(7,5),8:(9,0)}

dot_pos = list()
for k in dots:
    temp = list()
    for item in k:
        if item in pos:
            temp.append(pos[item])
    dot_pos.append(temp)
print dot_pos
```